# jQuery selecting multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, foreach

I have a list of p tags with a button next to each of them.
On click of that button, I want to make that specific p tag display in another div

My main problem is: I don't know how to make the two elements relate, so that when I click on a certain button, only the p tag that the button is next to will be affected. I can do this with one button and one paragraph, but I don't know how to do it with multiple.

Here is my HTML (on click of a button, move that p tag to the other div box):

```
        <div id="items">
             <p>item 1</p><button>add</button>
             <p>item 2</p><button>add</button>
             <p>item 3</p><button>add</button>
        </div>
        <div id="items2">

        </div>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm assuming you're setting the innerHTML = text. Try innerHTML += text.

Comment: Yes, I'm using innerHTML, but I'm not concatenating it. I'm pushing the added item to an empty array and then displaying the array each time I add a new item.

Comment: Can I see ALL of your code please?

Comment: Sure, here is my jquery so far: 

var products = Array();

$('#items button').click(function(x, el){
  $('p').each(function(i, element){ 
    var x = element.innerHTML;
    products.push(x);
    
    $('#items2').html(products);
  });
 
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the jQuery prev() to get the previous p tag as this:

```
var products = [];
$('#items button').click(function () {
    var x = $(this).prev().html();
    products.push(x);
    console.log(products);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works nicely. What if I wanted to keep the selected items in the first div (because I noticed that appendTo moves the actual item)?

Comment: Sweet! Thanks so much for your help. Also, just to make things more complicated...What if I didn't want to use the prev() function?

Comment: @tickerll if you didn't want to use `prev` then you'd be imposing arbitrary restrictions on the problem. Can you explain why you don't want to use `prev`? The correct solution will depend on your requirements.

Comment: @Dave I guess I wanted to see if there was a way to achieve this task with more logic and less jquery functions. These are the functions I'm restricted to: fadeIn()/fadeOut(), push(), each(), html(), val(), attr(), this
Perhaps more work and code, but challenging

Comment: @tickerll Still sounds very arbitrary. At best, you could add `parent()` to that list, iterate through the parent's children until you find the current node, store the loop index, iterate again until reaching the previous index, and apply to that. It's ugly and inefficient, but almost meets your requirements.

Comment: @tickerll you could always see how jQuery do it in their source code, witch is, ultimately, javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You cloud put the button inside the `<p>` tag and then call the `parent()` methond as this:

HTML:

```
<p>item 1
    <button>add</button>
</p>
```

JQuery:

```
$('button').click().parent().append("hello");
```

A better way would be to give the

tag inivudual class styles as this:

```
<p class="i1">item 1</p><button class="i1">add</button>
<p class="i2">item 2</p><button class="i1">add</button>

$('button').click(function(){
    var c = $(this).getClass();
    $("."+c).do_any_thing_u_want();  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`prev` is the command you're looking for:

```
$('button').prev().appendTo($('#items2'))
```

documentation: http://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: Thanks, it works nicely. What if I wanted to keep the selected items in the first div (because I noticed that appendTo moves the actual item)?

Comment: @tickerll you can use `clone` to copy, so `.prev().clone().appendTo(...)`